# Display order of array according to 1-9 and a-z

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a dynamic pyramid.

1. the user can add and remove blocks and the blocks are automatically named 
   with a number-letter combination, see the picture attached.
2. I have saved and sorted that combination in a array Array(3) [ "4p", "5i", 
   "6g" ][[image: Pyramid with blocks in the wrong order]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owKw8.png)

Problem:

1. I would like to display the blocks in the right order, meaning 1-9 and a-z, each time the user clicks "Add Block". As you can seen on the picture, currently 6g comes before 4p.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I have been trying to do this with the following

```
 function newOrder() {
    var oldOrder = values;
    values.sort();
    document.getElementByClassName('.values').innerHTML = values;
  }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Add Block Functionality
  let values = [];

  $('#add-block .button').click(function() {
    //determin widht of last div
    var lastwidth = $('.pyramid li:last-child .item').width();

    //calculation of next div
    if (lastwidth == null) {
      var plus = 90;
    } else {
      var plus = lastwidth + 190; //not sure why 190 but with this value they line up smoothly. Was expecting 0 and 100 for the values.
    }

    //create radom number
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;

    //create radom letter
    function randLetter() {
      var letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
      var letter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];

      return letter
    }

    //make letter available globally
    var resultLetter = randLetter();

    //create radom color
    function randColor() {
      var colors = ["green", "yellowgreen", "Chocolate", "goldenrod", "cadetblue", "firebrick", "magenta", "LightSeaGreen", "Peru", "Sienna", "SlateBlue", "Snow", "Tan", "Skyblue"];
      var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

      return color
    }

    //make color available gloabally
    var resultColor = randColor();
    var $block = $('<li><div class="item" style="width:' + plus + 'px; border-bottom: 60px solid ' + resultColor + ' ;"><input class="values" type="text" placeholder=" ' + number + resultLetter + ' " maxlength="2"> </div></li>');

    $('.pyramid').append($block);

    //save values

    values.push(number + resultLetter);
    values.sort();
    console.log(values);
});

  //Remove Block Functionality
  $('#remove-block .button').click(function() {
    value = $(".values", $('.pyramid li').last()).attr("placeholder").trim()//find last value added in pyramid//.attr()value of attribute placeholder,trim() is just for white space
    values.splice(values.indexOf(value), 1)//indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string. In this case it is the index of value, which is the last item in the array. Could be replaced by -1 I think
    console.log(values)
    $('.pyramid li').last().remove();
  })
});
```

```css
body, html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #101935;

}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li div.item {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 0px;
  width:  100px;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid #0488e0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

  li div.item:not(.item0){
  border-bottom: 60px solid #0488e0;
  border-left: 45px solid transparent;
  border-right: 45px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 0;
}

.values {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 20px;
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
}

.values:focus {
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .95);
box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
outline: none;
}

/*buttons section */
.buttons, #add-block, #remove-block{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#add-block span, #remove-block span {
  background-color: #edf7f6;
  padding: 5px 15px ;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color:#888;
  font-weight: 400;

}
#add-block .button, #remove-block .button{
  background-color: #0488e0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: background-color 250ms ease-in-out 100ms;
}

#add-block .button:hover, #remove-block .button:hover{
  background-color: #059BFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
  <body>

    <ul class="pyramid">
    </ul>

    <section class="buttons">
      <div id="add-block">
        <span>Add Block</span>
        <div class="button">+
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="remove-block">
        <span>Remove Block</span>
        <div class="button">-
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="resources/js/main.js"></script>

  </body>
```

Comment: I really don't wanna be rude,  but this is your 3rd question about this pyramid project of yours in one day. You can't expect people here to create this entire project for you step by step. You should do more research and try to do these things you're asking yourself, if you can't do it, keep searching for answer, challenge yourself a bit.

Comment: if you have a string "1z" and another "9a" which one should be on top of other?

Comment: So my idea was to place the numbers first. It this case it would be 1z. I have also experimented with document.getElementByClassName('.input').attr('placeholder'). innerHTML but I couldn't make them change their order according to the array....

Comment: @K.P. of course, I agree and I will keep researching, trying and experimenting. If you have a hint that points in the right direction, that would be appreciated. Currently, I am thinking of something like this document.getElementByClassName('.input').attr('placeholder')

Comment: If you need to place pieces in order why bother assigning each one a random alphanumeric?

Comment: @zer00ne Your right, of course! It's possible to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem which you need to solve is to have a sorted array where 
1-numbers should be in high to low order
2-if two numbers are same, their alphabets should be considered i.e high to low

you can use the Array's builtin sort function and provide custom comparator to achieve this

note:instead of concatenating number and alphabet you can also make an object with two properties that will help you write simplified comparator, while you can always concatenate both properties while rendering in html

```
var myStrings=[{num:'1',char:'z'},{num:'9',char:'a'},{num:'1',char:'b'},{num:'9',char:'d'}]

function myCustomComparator(a,b){
if (a.num<b.num) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (a.num>b.num) {
    return 1;
  }
  // a.num must be equal to b.num
  if (a.char<b.char) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if (a.char>b.char) {
    return 1;
  }
  //char must be equal too
  return 0;
}
myString.sort(myCustomComparator);
```

^above code is not tested though but you would have an idea by now how to use custom comparator to achieve what you want you can further read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)